# 302 error when post alot of data using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

```html
 $('#update_reading').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var values = [];
$("table tr").each((_, row) => {
  var value = {};
  $(row).find(":input[name='mono_cmr[]']").each((__, e) =>
    value['mono_cmr'] = $(e).val()
  );
  $(row).find(":input[name='mono_pmr[]']").each((__, e) =>
    value['mono_pmr'] = $(e).val()
  );
  $(row).find(":input[name='color_cmr[]']").each((__, e) =>
    value['color_cmr'] = $(e).val()
  );
  $(row).find(":input[name='color_pmr[]']").each((__, e) =>
    value['color_pmr'] = $(e).val()
  );
  $(row).find(":input[name='scn_cmr[]']").each((__, e) =>
    value['scn_cmr'] = $(e).val()
  );
  $(row).find(":input[name='scn_pmr[]']").each((__, e) =>
    value['scn_pmr'] = $(e).val()
  );
  $(row).find(":input[name='asset_id[]']").each((__, e) =>
    value['asset_id'] = $(e).val()
  );

  values.push(value);
  
});
// console.log(values)
values.shift();
values.shift();
values.shift();
values.shift();
var billing_date = $('#billing_date').val();         
 $("#overlay").fadeIn(300); 

  
  $.ajax({ 
  type: "POST", 
  dataType: "json", 
  url: 'billing/post_reading', 
  data: {'values': values,'billing_date': billing_date,"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
  
  success: function(data){ 
    // var msg =JSON.parse(data);
    
  } 
  }).done(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("#overlay").fadeOut(300);
      alert("Reading Updated Successfully"); 
    },
    
    500);
    
  }); 
  }); 
     
  </script>
```

i am using above to execute an Ajax call to post Data the script works well when i have like 10 input but when having like 400 rows to post i get 302 not found error am unable to find why am getting this redirect and data is not posted. The below is what is seen in inspect[image]

how can i handle this issue?

the request also shows blocked
[image]

Comment: In your network tab, you have a response tab, it will give you more info. Check laravel.log if it gives you more info. The 302 http code is *not* an error code

Comment: The redirect was because of CSRF token error i had to ass it separate as header